# Is it possible to change a .click() function in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a .click() function in the header of my page, is it possible to overwrite it later in the page?

**For example if I have this in the header:**

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("a.lol").click(function () { 
        alert("aaa");
    });
});
</script>
```

Would it be possible to change `$("a.lol")` to alert something else, and not alert "aaa"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("a.lol").click(function () { // initially the click event
        alert("aaa");
    });
    $("a.lol").off('click');// off the click event
    $("a.lol").on('click',function () { // again bind new click event with on()
        alert("new click");
    });
});
```

Read [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) and [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off)

Comment: It's my understanding that off() will not remove a handler added with click(). From the docs: "The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()."

Comment: @BrianStephens I just tried it. Works fine for me. If you [look at the source code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.click) you'll see that `.click` simply maps to `.on` internally (as do `.bind` and `.delegate`).

Comment: @Blazemonger Good to know! I was never sure if I was interpreting the documentation right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**.unbind()**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) and then "put it back" adding a new handler.

```
$("a.lol").unbind('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off)

```
$("a.lol").off('click');
```

and to add back use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)

```
$("a.lol").on('click',functionName);
```

or

```
$("a.lol").on('click',function () { 
    //code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("a.lol").off('click')` to remove all click handlers. Afterwards, you can install new ones.

For older versions of jQuery, use `unbind()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to remove the current handler with [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and then call click() again with the new handler.

```
// Some code
$("a.lol").off("click")
$("a.lol").click(function () { 
    alert("ooo");
});
```

PS: Depending on your use case you could maybe use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) which would trigger the handler only once and then remove itself